# What are these wire connectors called?

Tags: wiring, fitting

I'm rewiring this device and the board on the device has these white plastic connectors. The existing wires terminate in a sort of metal slug that makes them a snug fit in their slots on the connectors.

[image: Picture of connector]

What is the name of these terminators/fittings? Are they available at hardware stores?

Comment: Do the connectors detach from the board as a unit?  (I'd try with the connector on the right -- it looks like it should come off as a housing+contacts unit)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, they do.

Comment: My mouth wants to say "Molex connector" but there are a variety of workalike connectors.  The common thing is they are *not intended* as access points for those wires.  If you're trying to tap one of these wires, they will have provided other places to do that.

Comment: @Harper I'm not trying to connect to the existing wires, I need to add new wires to the empty slots. Molex connectors look promising, but they're $12 on Amazon. Would a hardware store carry them?

Comment: Note many of those voids do not have contacts in them.  Adding contacts to that type of connector (if you could even *find* them) is a rather delicate operation even in the factory. So it's *extremely unlikely* that the manufacturer intends a consumer/installer to add contacts in the field.  It's only intended as an internal interconnect, and tying to them would be akin to "hacking the device".  I would get the furnace manual.  Trying to attach here is a lost cause, they surely provided an alternative.

Comment: Are you looking for the connector, or the metal tab that connects to the wire and slides into the slot? The connector is molex, but you can sometimes find the pins alone. If you know the size needed, you can search for electrical connector pins and the size. https://i.stack.imgur.com/150Ri.jpg

Comment: @JeffCates I'm looking for the metal tab that slides into the slot. Is "electrical connector pin" what I should be searching for?

Comment: Yes. Its the pin you want

Comment: It looks like molex to me check out electronics like jameco, McMaster Carr, digikey. You will also need a molex crimper to properly fold the ears over the wires.  But as Harper points out + there are other brands, they also come in diferent sizes based on the ampacity these look like the smaller ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the feedback I got in the comments, I purchased some [pin and socket connectors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LVIHFAI). They ended up being bigger than the ones already present, but they still fit and work for the intended purpose.